# Declaring labels after function

Tags: oz, mozart

I have this code in Oz:

```
declare
fun {NewCounter}
C Bump Read in
C={NewCell 0}
fun {Bump}
C:=@C+1
@C
end
fun {Read}
@C
end
counter(bump:Bump read:Read)
end
```

I have two questions:

1) C, Bump and Read labels are declared after the NewCounter function. Are they global labels ?

2) The NewCounter function return the record counter. Why do I have to specify the name of the record (counter), considering that no other function will never explicitly invoke it?

Answer (score 0):

C, Bump and Read are local variables (part of the NewCounter function).

The label of the returned record is probably not important here. But client code *could* use the label. Also it can be useful to see in the debugger.